# JQuery Mobile vclick event only fires once

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to do a simple button rollover, changing it's icon when it's vclicked, but really don't get why the vclick event is only fired once, can someone shed some light on this? I get the same result if I use "click" or attach the event directly to the button element.

JSFiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/w7quoyn4/

```
$('#btnAddToCart').on('vclick', function () {

    console.log("btnAddToCart vclick event fired");

    if ($(this).attr('data-icon', "plus")) {
        $(this).attr('data-icon', "minus").button().button("refresh");
    } else {
        $(this).attr('data-icon', "plus").button().button("refresh");
    }

});
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `if ($(this).attr('data-icon', "plus"))` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Thanks! I'll get to that as soon as I get the event to fire :)

Comment: The event does fire. Unfortunately, the conditional statement I quoted above always returns `true`, so no visible changes occur on the next events.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: Even if you correct that mistake it only fires once (and is already uses a delegated event in the Fiddle). There is *another* reason for the problem :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, indeed you're right. The calls to `button()` are also a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in your code.

First, the conditional expression `$(this).attr('data-icon', "plus")` invokes the setter form of [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), which will always return the jQuery object its is called on. Since objects are always `true` in a boolean context, your `else` branch will never be taken.

To fix that, you could invoke the getter form of `attr()` and compare the result:

```
if ($(this).attr("data-icon") == "plus") {
    // ...
}
```

Then again, the calls to `button()` are the heart of the matter. The appropriate method to use would be [buttonMarkup()](http://api.jquerymobile.com/buttonMarkup/), but it is deprecated since release 1.4 (and will be removed in 1.5).

The actual solution is to add and remove the appropriate classes yourself, as in:

```
$(document).on("vclick", "#btnAddToCart", function () {
    console.log("btnAddToCart vclick event fired");
    $(this).toggleClass("ui-icon-plus ui-icon-minus");
});
```

You can see the results in [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w7quoyn4/9/).

Comment: Okay, you beat me to finished answer. Would only suggest `$this.closest('[data-id]').attr("data-id")` as a more portable alternative :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, I had the same idea at first, but if the `#btnAddToCart` element also exposes a `data-id` attribute, then `closest()` will match it instead of its grandparent and mayhem will ensue. `parents().eq(1)` is shorter but less efficient than `parent().parent()`, so I opted to leave that part of the code as it was :)

Comment: How about `$this.parent().closest('[data-id]').attr("data-id")`? Whenever I see hierarchical dependencies I start to worry :)

Comment: That's a good middle ground :) I agree worrying about such dependencies is good practice (I'll still let the questioner worry about it, though).